# column_names for non DB model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What is the equivalent of the ActiveRecord column_names method for non DB models.

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
end
```

Method should return something like this ["first_name", "last_name"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr_accessor` is shorthand for defining getters and setters, so the closest I can think of to making a `column_names` method for this class without constructing any additional scaffolding is this:

`Person.instance_methods(false).reject { |m| m =~ /.*=/ }`

You call `instance_methods` to get the getters and setters, then you reject the setters. Passing in false to `instance_methods` excludes methods defined on the superclass (in this case, `Object`).

Comment: Had also to exclude some callback methods: `People.instance_methods(false).reject { |m| m =~ /.*callback|.*=/ }`. Wouldn't it be useful to have a method like column_names in the ActiveModel code?

Comment: What would it mean though? The distinction between column names and virtual attributes was what existed in the DB. If you want something like that, you're going to have to draw the line between what is and isn't a "column" yourself. Maybe with some class-level registry of said "columns"

Comment: True. I mean the method shouldn't be called column_names but it would be nice to have something that returns all names of virtual attributes.